# CoffeeScript and Named Functions

Tags: functions, coffeescript

[Elsewhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24038/cleanest-way-to-close-over-a-counter-in-coffeescript/24052?noredirect=1#comment37204_24052), an argument has arisen over the terminology of a named function in CoffeeScript. In particular someone referred to something like this:

```
 foo = ->
    console.log("bar")
```

as a named function. But its been objected that everything in CoffeeScript is anonymous functions and there are no named functions. This is certainly true, CoffeeScript only has function expressions which can then be stored in a variable. But I don't think that means it is wrong to call this a named function.

As I see it, it is a named function because its a function that has been given a name. True, its not a named function in the same way that some other languages have named functions, but I think its close enough that it's not inappropriate to call it a named function. To insist otherwise just seems to be nitpicking.

Am I out to lunch in thinking that insisting that this isn't a named function is just nitpicking?

Comment: Isn't this whole question just, well, nitpicking? :-)

Comment: @Mat, yes it seems I can't avoid nitpicking about nitpicking

Comment: For the small pool of programmers that I talk to (outside of programmers.SE that is), they mostly say to use JavaScript's named functions for use as "classes" (constructors), while anonymous functions stored in variables for plain old functions.

Comment: "Just nitpicking" implies the answer doesn't matter, and that understanding the subtleties of a language isn't a worthy goal.

Comment: I could look at it analogously to CoffeeScript: `foo = ->` is just a plain old function, whilst `class Foo` is a constructor. I see no reason why `foo = ->` should strictly be called anonymous.

Comment: Sure at the technical level `foo = ->` represents a variable referring to an anonymous function, but I don't see that as *your* job for explaining the low-levels of a higher level idea.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I dislike the whole idea. People don't even know why it would matter. There is a significant difference to anybody who cares about debug in Chrome, for instance, or having identifiable constructor names for object instances.

Answer (score 21):

CoffeeScript is inexorably tied to JavaScript, and JavaScript differentiates between the following expressions:

```
function foo() { ... }
var foo = function () { ... }
```

In fact, you can even write:

```
var foo = function bar () { ... }
```

Since this difference matters in JavaScript, it makes sense to use the same terms when talking about CoffeeScript. However, CoffeeScript does not support anything like the `function foo ()` syntax, so we can say it does not have "named" functions.

In a sense, the name is part of the function definition in the `function foo() { ... }`, where in the other case you just create a function and assign it to a variable. This is reflected, for example, in the (nonstandard) `name` property of functions: in the first case, `foo.name` will give you `"foo"` and in the second it will give you `""`.

Additionally, in JavaScript, these also differ in terms of how they get introduced to the scope: the first version is "hoisted" and available throughout its scope where the second definition is only available after it's assigned.

Basically, just think of it as JavaScript-specific jargon, which is transferred to CoffeeScript because CoffeeScript is so closely related to JS.

Comment: It's true that there isn't such a thing as a `function foo () {}`. However, you can still initialize a named function via the `class` construct. Just that the compiled CoffeeScript (the resulting JavaScript) is much more verbose than how most would write a named function.

Comment: And also, there's a technical caveat: your `foo` function's body will not be hoisted.

Comment: jelivs: no problem. One correction from the last comment I wrote on your answer: your `class foo`'s function body will not be hoisted to the top of the file.

Comment: Since CoffeeScript doesn't make the distinction between named and anonymous functions, can we really say that the terminology is transfered to CoffeeScript? Javascript's distinction simply doesn't mean anything in that language.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: It matters because CoffeeScript is *so close* to JavaScript. After all, the "golden rule" is: *"It's just JavaScript"*.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis, I think of CoffeeScript as being quite different from JavaScript, for me at least it has a whole different "feel". But I see where you are coming from.

Comment: The one problem I have with CoffeeScript's non-support of named functions is that the debugger backtrace can't show names which are not there. :-/

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that the user explicitly stated they were turning an "anonymous function into a named function", both terms having a strong, existing meanings and notably different functionalities in in the JavaScript world. Given the existing meaning, the were doing no such thing, and I pointed this out.

CoffeeScript is not so far removed from JavaScript that you should be redefining terms they both share to mean something else in one language. CoffeeScript doesn't exist in some bubble, removed from its JavaScript implementation the way you might argue that C++ is separated from Assembly. Knowing the difference between an anonymous function and a named function *matters*, because if you expect your "named" CoffeeScript function to behave like an *actual* named function, you're going to be disappointed:

```
doStuff() # I cause an error

# ... later

doStuff = (x,y) ->
  alert("Were I actually a named function, this would work!")
```

The equivalent JavaScript would work fine, with a *real* named function:

```
doStuff(); // I work just fine!

// later....

function doStuff() {
  alert("I'm a real named function!")
}
```

You might be right that I'm just "nitpicking", but so what? The subtle points in computer programming *matter*, and being "technically" correct is important. It's the difference between writing code that happens to work, and actually understanding why your code is *correct*.

Comment: If I tried your example in Python, for example, it still wouldn't work. So I'm not sure that has anything to do with named vs anonymous functions.

Comment: @WinstonEwert See my update. Python really doesn't have anything to do with it...

Comment: @meager, my point is that named functions don't necessarily act that way, although they do in Javascript. Therefore, hoisting itself doesn't disqualify CoffeeScript's functions from being considered named.

Comment: Yes, you have to understand that all functions in CoffeeScript are anonymous (actually, I'd prefer to say that they are all function expressions). But that doesn't mean that we can't be a bit loose with terminology sometimes. That's why I think its nitpicking to insist that you can't ever call them named functions.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I out to lunch in thinking that insisting that this isn't a named function is just nitpicking?

No. After all, in terms of semantics, your function reference is stored in a variable, which you can refer to via a variable *name*.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not a nitpick, imo. I use it extensively for readability:

```
readfile()
dothis()
dothat()
thistoo()
writefile()

function readfile() {
    ...
}
...
```

Thus:

Real named function in "coffeescript"

```
hello()

`function hello() {`
console.log 'hello'
dothings()
`}`
```

You escape pure JS via the backtick `

Note that you can't indent on your function body.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste time arguing with pedants.  It's never fruitful.  Yes, everyone knows what you mean by a "named function" in CoffeeScript, even if it's technically incorrect.  No, using technically incorrect but widely understood terminology has no bearing on the correctness or incorrectness of the proposed solution.  Is it possible to be more precise without gaining some awkwardness of phrasing?  Probably not.  However, that doesn't mean people will let it slide.  Just imagine [this guy](https://xkcd.com/386/) on the other end of the conversation.

The reason it's technically incorrect is because you haven't named the function, you've named a *reference* to the function.  Consider:

```
foo = bar = ->
  console.log "What's my name?"
```

What's the function's name?  `foo` and `bar` are both referencing the same function, but have different names.  Also, either `foo` or `bar` could be reassigned at any time to reference a different function, or even a different type altogether, without changing the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

So, the way I read this is like this:

When you declare a function in a JavaScript console using

```
var foo = function() { ... }
```

and then invoke `foo` without parentheses, it returns

```
function() { ... }
```

However, if you define it using

```
function foo() { ... }
```

and then invoke `foo` again without parentheses, it returns

```
function foo() { ... }
```

In the first case, I'd say you're declaring a variable named "foo" storing an anonymous function in it. In the second case, I'd say you're actually declaring a named function called "foo".

Because CoffeeScript uses the first pattern, I'd agree that it's technically correct that CoffeeScript's functions are all anonymous functions being stored in named variables.